# Turbo C++ program getting stuck

Tags: c++, debugging, turbo-c++

The program itself works correctly, does what it's supposed to (seperate the words in a sentence and print them out) and does not crash. However, i cannot exit from the program. It just gets stuck. I even tried giving an exit(0) in the end but it didn't work.

Can you please tell me what's wrong?

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<process.h>

typedef char* string;

void main()
{
clrscr();

string s;

cout << "\nEnter something : ";
gets(s);

int i;

for (i = 0; i < strlen(s); ++i)
{
if ( s[i] != 32 )// && ( !isalnum(s[i-1]) || i == 0 ) )
{
    char *word = s;
    int end = 0;

    for (; s[i] != 32 && i < strlen(s); ++i);

    if (i == strlen(s)) end = 1;
    else * (word + i) = '\0';

    cout << "\n" << word;

    if (end) break;

    strcpy(s, s+i+1);
    i = -1;
}
}
```

}

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Sorry, my initial program contained a system("pause") and I've removed it. But it still doesn't solve the problem. The program still does not terminate.

Comment: I know that using this obsolete c library is not good, but I have no option. Turbo C++ is the mandatory compiler for computer science in my school and so, I have to use it.

Comment: You may want to go to a different school.  It does you no good to learn a non standard 20+ year old version of C++.  You will find you have to relearn the language if you want to use modern C++.

Comment: Please take a typing / keyboarding class.  Your `typedef char * string` is evil.  There is a C++ class called `std::string`, and your `typedef` is confusing with `std::string`.

Comment: Please refrain from using ASCII number instead of character constants.  In other words use ' ' instead of 32 or for testing purposes, `std::ispace()`.

Comment: After you input the string, you should call `strlen()` and store into a constant variable.  The string should not change after you input.  Also, the `strlen` counts each character in your string, taking a lot of execution time when you call it.  If you use `std::string` instead, it saves the length so it doesn't calculate each time.

Comment: @NathanOliver: He'll struggle to find one not teaching Turbo C++ in India. The Indian computer education system is laughably substandard. He'll need to find a different country.

Comment: Prefer to use `bool` for *Boolean* variables, which have only `true` or `false` values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Undefined Behavior**

You declare a pointer and don't initialize it (you don't make it point to anything):

```
string s;
// a.k.a. char * s;
```

Next, you input into it:

```
gets(string);
```

This is known as undefined behavior:  writing to an unknown address.  A nice operating system and platform would segfault.

In computer programming, you need to allocate memory either by using an array:

```
char s[256];
```

or dynamic allocation:

```
string s = new char[256];
```

before you put values in, either from input or elsewhere.

Comment: Or use `std::string` like a sane person

Answer (score 3):

**You told it to do that. Remove `system("pause");`**

And, please, stop using the C library, and headers/tools from the 1980s. We've moved on from MS DOS in the intervening time. If you want marketable skills, learn actual ISO C++ (which was invented in 1998, and has been updated three times in the nearly two decades since then).